# How to implement a linear gradient background with a curved divider

Tags: android, xml

I have a layout in an android application and would like to implement a linear gradient where the top of the layout is white and the bottom is black with a curved divider in between. I have tried with the code below but it does not seem to draw the gradient as expected. How do I correctly modify the gradient file to achieve the the desired look?

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- White background at the top half -->
    <item
        android:top="50%"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- Black background at the bottom half -->
    <item
        android:bottom="50%"
        android:drawable="#000000" />

    <!-- Curve divider -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp" android:bottomRightRadius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:top="120dip">
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/red" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="240dip">
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Like a diagonal divider where the left of that diagonal is black and the right white